# изменить тег мета в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

нужно изменить это в теме.

пробовал хук

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_in_head', 11 ); 
function insert_in_head(){
 echo '<meta property="og:title" content="new title tag" />';
 echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/big.jpg" />';
}
```

работает но меняет не там где нужно.

Comment: add_action не меняет. он просто подвязывает вызов функции. меняет add_filter

Comment: Если у вас кастомная тема, можете добавить непосредственно в шаблон темы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так для заголовка

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'my_custom_title');

function my_custom_title( $title ) {

  $title['title'] = 'My new title';

  return $title;
}
```

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="https://noor.pixeldima.com/noor-classic/wp-content/uploads/sites/31/2017/10/slack-imgs.jpg" />

Вот от этой строки не могу ни избавиться, ни изменить. Здесь стоит фото темы что я взял в работу, и при постинге в соц сети она привязывается в сообщение. Подскажите как или изменить или убрать

Comment: Вот и перформулируйте вопрос на основании коммента. Ответ будет совсем другим.